# ActiveX-textbox does not increase dynamically

Tags: excel, activexobject

I guess this is a trivial question in Excel, but I've taken the liberty to ask anyway :)

I have inserted a textbox (ActiveX-object) in a sheet with a fixed size (158,25 x 204). I want to keep this size, but I want the textbox to increase dynamically in height whenever the user has reached the last line (line 11) in the textbox instead of pushing the text up.

I've uploaded a screenshot of the textbox' property field.

[image: property field]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Up towards the top of the Properties there is AutoSize. Set it to True.

With the WordWrap property set to True, the text box width will be preserved and it will grow down as required.

Comment: Hey Mark. I've now set the Autosize and the WordWrap property to True. The textbox is increasing as more text is written (which is what I wanted). However, the initial fixed size (158,25 x 204) is not preserved.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can preserve the size and have the height increase - they seem to be mutually exclusive. It has to be one or the other.